# how to resolve the error "ADMIN option not granted for role 'my_role_1'"

Tags: oracle, permissions, oracle-12c, role

I am trying to grant a role to user.

```
grant my_role_1 to ktest1 with admin option;
```

But i am getting the below error

```
Error report - ORA-01932: ADMIN option not granted for role 'my_role_1'
01932. 00000 -  "ADMIN option not granted for role '%s'
*Cause:    The operation requires the admin option on the role.
*Action:   Obtain the grant option and re-try.
```

I have also tried the below statement. Still i am getting the same error. I am able to grant different roles but only with this role i am getting this error.

```
grant my_role_1 to ktest1;
```

Comment: Which user is trying to perform the `GRANT`?  Who made the `ROLE` in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have the admin option yourself on my_role_1, so you cannot grant the role to other users. Get your DBA to grant the admin option for my_role_1 to you and you will be then be able grant the role to ktest1.